# Implementation of D (differentiation) in PID

Tags: c, pid-controller

I am implementing a PID controller for motor speed control. I am done with implementing the PI control and it works perfectly fine for me. In the specification I have been told to implement a filtering technique by using the following equation for the D part:

[image]

Now what I understand so far, is that `s` represents `"dx/dt"` generally which corresponds to the rate of change of error, but here I can relate it with the rate of change of feedback. `Td/N` is for limiting the overall gain output (hope I got this right).
Now to represent this in terms of C code, I tried the following way:

```
        s = (CurrentFeedback()-Old_Feedback)*100/(MaxFeedback()); //to calculate the % change in feedback
        s = s*1000/sampleTime;      //1000 is multiplied because sampleTime is in milliseconds
        D = (Td*s)/(1+(s*Td/N));
        D = D*KP;   //Kp is multiplied as per the standard pid equation.

        Old_Feedback = CurrentFeedback();
        PID = P+I-D;
```

Well the results by adding D are not what I have predicted. 
I just want to know if I implemented the D portion equation correctly? Am I making any mistakes in my understanding of the basic maths of differentiation?

**NOTE:** I am not in liberty to change the recalculate the kp,ti,td as it comes directly from the VFD.

Comment: Try http://www.embedded.com/design/prototyping-and-development/4211211/PID-without-a-PhD, "PID without a PhD".  There is a clear section on the derivative implementation.

Comment: When you declare Old_Feedback = CurrentFeedback() is wrong. You shold read the value with CurrentFeedback() and store it in temp. variable CurrentFeedback_tmp, then use that value everywher in that ISR, because anytime you call a fct CurrentFeedback() it retreives the actual value which will be different each time you recall it.

Comment: "the results by adding D is not what I have predicted" - what have you predicted? Why are they different?

Comment: There is great potential for integer overflows here. What are the types of the involved variables and have you considered the maximum values of them?

Comment: s,D is S32, KP,Td and N U16. sample time is U32
I considered maximum values of variable as per the max value possible of particular data types.

Comment: Why are you doing P+I-D? has the sign for D been swapped somewhere? I would have expected the D term to add to the result and not subtract. Can you fix the time period of you processing and sensing loop? It makes life a lot simpler if you can sample at a fixed rate. Also if your sample time is in milliseconds should you not be dividing by 1000 to get seconds?

Comment: I can not divide because my device does not support floating points. So I am multiplying numerator with 100 you can see that in code. In 1st point you are right it should be P + I +D. I think there was of problem in implementing the equation . I will post the answer in few days once i am done with testing my codel

Answer (score 1):

I have 3 points to share :

1-I will tell you why people mess with D term interms of sign , PID= P + I + D but , D = kd* (error -olderror) , and in position control if you are approaching the set point , always olderror is < error so D term will be negative , and thus it decreases the output and prevent the overshoot.

2-Regarding time , donot divide or use time . since you are using embedded microcontroller use just make a time constant and cancel it from all equations : for example use a timer interrupt to generate 1ms time constant and call your function inside .

3-Why you are using PID for velocity control , 90% of the time PI is enough in speed control , since D here is more like accelaration control .

Hope that helps